# cocos2d dragging a sprite by touch without gaps

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to drag a sprite by touch on it. If the touch is outside the sprite, it should NOT move.

When user touch on the sprite and drag it, a path is drawn behind. This path should not be broken (like gaps between paths). There should be one consistent path at all the times.

I am using mysprite.position to set new position of sprite same as current touch location.
But there are gaps if user touches a point slightly out of path.
I also tried using CCMoveTo action but that delays the path drawing and if user is drawing very fast then it looks bad that sprite is following behind.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[mySprite runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.0f position:touchLocation]];

-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   if(CGRectContainsPoint([mySprite boundingBox], currentTouchPoint)){
        CGPoint translation = ccpSub(currentTouchPoint, lastTouchPoint);
        CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(mySprite.position, translation);
        mySprite.position = newPos;
        [touchPoints addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(currentTouchPoint)];
        [touchPoints addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(lastTouchPoint)];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to achieve it?

Comment: interpolate between touch locations because two touch events may have locations very far apart if the user moves the finger quickly

Comment: can you please suggest how to do it?

Comment: Anyone has some good ideas to achieve it? Please share.